# Поочередно вызвать методы

Tags: golang

У меня есть структура:

```
type MyStruct struct {}

func (s *MyStruct) Method1() float32 {
    return 0
}

func (s *MyStruct) Method2() float32 {
    return 0
}

func (s *MyStruct) Method3() float32 {
    return 0
}
```

Мне требуется опросить каждый метод и выбрать максимальное значение среди тех, что они вернут. Очевидное решение -- написать несколько условий:

```
s := MyStruct{}
m1 := s.Method1()
m2 := s.Method2()
m3 := s.Method3()
if m1 > m2 {
  if m1 > m3 {
    fmt.Println(m1)
  } else {
    fmt.Println(m3)
  }
}else{
  if m2 > m3 {
    fmt.Println(m2)
  } else {
    fmt.Println(m3)
  }
}
```

Но такое решение кажется силшком сложным для случая, когда методов много. Вероятно, задачу можно решить при помощи пакета reflect и цикла. Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

Comment: добавьте в массив и выберите максимальное значение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

просто добавьте результат в массив и в конце пройдитесь по массиву и выберите максимальное

```
for _, e := range v {
    if e > max {
        max = e
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы хотите рефлекта? Его есть у меня.

Данный код тупой, тормозной (O(n²) + оверхед рефлекта), небезопасный, и вообще за такое руки надо отрывать:

```
methodNames := []string{
    "Method1",
    "Method2",
    "Method3",
}

s := &MyStruct{}
v := reflect.ValueOf(s)
var max float64 = -1
for _, methodName := range methodNames {
    res := v.MethodByName(methodName).Call(nil)[0].Float()
    if res > max {
        max = res
    }
}

fmt.Println(max)
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/fQ1GZZyRFdv.

Любой нормальный человек будет использовать вариант коллеги Senior Pomidor.

Comment: но мы все тут ненормальные )